# Algorithm to handle positive rating if there is huge difference between the number of reviews

Tags: data-mining, ranking, percentage

We have two products P1 and P2. P1 has total 1000 number of reviews and p2 has 200 reviews.

Positive rating of P1 is 85% (85% users are saying it's a good product) Positive rating of P2 is 90% (90% users are saying it's a good product)

Now if we see technically P1 is better than P2 because 850 users are saying it's a good product while only 180 users are saying P2 is good.

How to solve this problem so that we can show a fair result? if possible please share the logic or algorithm.

Comment: Why not just compare the proportions? You do need to define what you mean by a fair result.

Comment: Actually, we are saying P1 has 85% positive votes and P2 has 90% positive votes so when the user would see this he would like to prefer P2 but P1 better than P2. Here I am tiring to simplify it so that P1 can be highlighted. May be by giving adding a factor... but not able to develop a formula which can fit here...  @mdewey pls let me know if you have any idea for the same.